# Disable logging for Spring Integration

Tags: logging, log4j, spring-integration

I am using log4j in my project and i do not want to see any of the integration related information in my application log.

So i did following and it worked fine

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration=OFF, webapp, stdout
```

However recently i have introduced a JDBC outbound adapter as below

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
    data-source="pooledDataSource" 
    channel="bstListenerResultToDatabaseLogChannel"
    query="INSERT INTO INTEGRATION_LOG 
        (unique_id,flow,status,type,process_start_date,process_end_date) 
        VALUES(:payload.uniqueId, :payload.flow, :payload.status, :payload.messageType, :payload.processStartDate, :payload.processEndDate)"
    />
```

Then in the Log file it started appearing the above sql insert statement as below

```
DEBUG (JdbcTemplate.java:616) - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO INTEGRATION_LOG(unique_id,flow,status,type ......
```

I assume that the JDBC output adapters use JDBC templates to execute the sql statements and it appears in the logs as a result of that. Is there any way of get rid of these kind of log entries through the log4j

Thanks,
Keth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to turn off logging for `org.springframework.jdbc` too.

I would suggest, however, that `OFF` will make it difficult for you to debug problems.

I would suggest `WARN` or `ERROR` instead (including for integration) - then log messages will only be emitted for problems with configurations and/or at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. however i can not turn off or restrict the org.springframework.jdbc as we use spring jdbc templates heavily in our DAO layer

Comment: Yes, but it's unusual to log at `DEBUG` level in production (which is where that message comes from).